# Use of enough, example from Murphy grammar course

Tags: grammar

What is the correct sentence:
I know English enough to read a newspaper   OR
I know enough English to read a newspaper.

Comment: Please say which one you think it is, and why. Perhaps you already ‘know enough’ to answer the question. Otherwise this is only a homework question, and consequently off topic on EL&U. Please visit the site's [Help Centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see which questions are on topic. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

Either could be correct, depending on what you want to emphasize.

- I know English enough to read a newspaper.

You are sufficiently familiar with the words, verb conjugations, and grammar & syntactic rules of English.
This could also be expressed as

- I know English **well** enough to read a newspaper.

=====================

- I know enough English  to read a newspaper.

You have learned (perhaps by rote) a large number of set phrases and patterns, and are good at guessing from context the ones you don't know.

Comment: '... if your study book is a stickler for form, it might insist that the form with well is more correct, and thus that the one without well is not correct, and that therefore you should choose the below.' That may be true, but you fail to support _your_ statement with any references.

Comment: Are you hoping for references backing up my interpretations of the two renderings, or for my claim that "either could be correct", or both?  My conjecture about the OP's study book is nothing but a conjecture; I could easily take that part out if it seems unjustifiable.

Comment: 'I know English enough' ...  is correct [without the 'well']'. It's not enough to label certain grammars 'sticklers for form'; their main _job_ is to point out what's acceptable. If you disagree with what they call 'unacceptable', you need to give evidence from other grammars. To pinch a quote from Janus Bahs Jacquet, 'With no sources or even explanations as to why you consider the [first variant correct] this seems more like just stating an opinion than giving an actual, factual answer.'

Comment: So it seems you are objecting to my straw man of the hypothetical "stickler". I looked up the Murphy grammar course, but I would have had to buy the book to see what it actually says about this.  Or maybe the OP would be so kind as to enlighten us in that regard. Meanwhile, if I understand you correctly, you are saying that the **well** is not needed. I never said that it was; I said "this could also be expressed as".

Comment: Look at what tchrist says about answers given without any supporting evidence: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely ... personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' ODO, for instance, requires that this usage of 'enough' should not be preceded by a noun: 

**enough**: 
1 To the required degree or extent (used after an adjective, adverb, or verb):

Answer (score -1):

Well, what you should have done is check the frequencies of the **core/critical** **expressions** utilized at Google Books (not vanilla/normal Google):

["know English **well** enough to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%20know%20English%20enough%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22know%20English%20well%20enough%20to%22)
About 6,480 results

["know English enough to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%20know%20English%20enough%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22know%20English%20enough%20to%22)
About 1,170 results

This clearly shows that a majority supports the version with "well" (and that might be recommended in some books, and justifiably so). However, the other version seems to be well tolerated and used by native speakers.